# Dumping pickle is not working with rb+

Tags: python, pickle

Why pickle file is not modified? But after I uncomment the line it works?

```
with open(PATH, "rb+") as fp:
    mocks_pickle = pickle.load(fp)
    mocks_pickle['aa'] = '123'
    # pickle.dump(mocks_pickle, open(PATH, 'wb'))
    pickle.dump(mocks_pickle, fp)
```

Comment: But r+ opens a file for both reading and writing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to seek to the beginning of the file with `fp.seek(0)` before dumping the object.

If you don't seek you append the new pickle to the end of the file.
And when you `pickle.load` from the file you only get the first there is in the file.

```
with open(PATH, "rb+") as fp:
    mocks_pickle = pickle.load(fp)
    mocks_pickle['aa'] = '123'
    fp.seek(0)
    pickle.dump(mocks_pickle, fp)
```